# An SVG component inside an "i" element doesn't change color when the div is on hover

Tags: html, css

I want the "icons" to turn yellow on hover just like the text but it only worked when i put `.navbar-list-item i:hover`. In that case it changes the color ONLY when the icon itself is on hover, not the div that has it.

It happens because I have a default color set earlier.

CSS:

```
.navbar-list-item:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #F3D63B;
    transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.3s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-list">
            <a href="/">
                <li class="navbar-list-item">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-lemon"></i>
                </li>
            </a>
            <li class="navbar-list-item">Item 1</li>
            <li class="navbar-list-item">Item 2</li>
            <li class="navbar-list-item">Item 3</li>
            <li class="navbar-list-item">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically I just had to add **`.navbar-list-item:hover i`** in the same CSS snippet and it works.

Here's what it looks like:

```
.navbar-list-item:hover, .navbar-list-item:hover i{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #F3D63B;
    transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).